# Spring beans and classes

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, javabeans

I'm trying to discover how beans work and also I'm trying to follow the spring official bean tutorial ( http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html ).

I am trying to write an app which simply loads a bean.xml file and gets a bean from it, setting it to a variable.

```
Car car = (Car) beans.getBean("car");
```

Here is exactly how my bean.xml looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="person" class="com.vlad.myapp.Person">
    <property name="name"><value>"Bob"</value></property>
    <property name="lastName"><value>"Bobson"</value></property>
    <property name="id"><value>1</value></property>
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

Here is my Person.java class:

```
    package com.vlad.myapp;

public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String last_name;
    private int id;

    public Person(String name,String last_name,int id)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String name()
    {
        return name;

    }

    public String last_name(){
        return last_name;
    }
    public int id()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setLastName(String name){
        this.last_name = name;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }



}
```

In my controller I'm trying to load the bean file and get one of it's beans as shown in the Car example:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext beans = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
    Person person = (Person) beans.getBean("person");
    model.addAttribute("person",person);
    return "home";
```

In the view I'm trying to simply print out the name of the Person:

```
<p>The person's name is: ${person.name()}</p>
```

However all I get from my page when loaded is :

> The person's name is:

Looks as if the view is not able to get the variable?

Here is my directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Why do you read the documentation for the Spring 1.2 version? The current Spring version is 4.0.2. 1.2 is completely obsolete.

Comment: @JBNizet it looks as if I'm not able to find a up to date tutorial about spring beans. Did the syntax change that much? Is this method outdated? I've seen recent tutorials using this

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/. It's linked directly from the spring home page: http://spring.io. But you should start by learning and respecting Java naming conventions, and Java Bean conventions. Also, you shouldn't create a new Spring context from your controller to get the bean. Instead, the bean should be injected into the controller. That's the whole point of dependency injection. And yes, 1.2 is completele outdated, especially when it comes to Spring MVC.

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop reading about Spring 1.2!
2. Use POJO - getters and setters (change method name to getName() etc.)
3. Try `<p>The person's name is: ${person.name}</p>` instead of ${person.name()}

Comment: @pospeq I changed all of my getters to respect that pojo principle. Also I have used ${person.name} however it still has the same output

Comment: @Bula Try to use System.out.print(person.getName()) before this line model.addAttribute("person",person) and see the output

Comment: @pospeq it looks as if my server stops and says that it cannot find the file bean.xml. Looking at my directory structure ( see post ) I'm not sure why this would be the case

Answer (score 0):

You need to create POJO. Your getters are wrong, it should be:

```
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getLastName(){ 
        return last_name;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
```